# How to combine both numerical data and categorial data for numeric prediction in time series LSTM

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I am working on  power prediction using time series LSTM. I have implemented the model and my predictions were okay.
Now i want to consider adding the weekday for each time series so i'll get a better power prediction, because the each day (Mon to Fri) has it own effect on the power even at different time.
I one hot encoded the week days and i now have 8 columns (Power and 7 days of the week). I have generated a sequence but i get alot of errors.

I'm yet to get the best practise on solving this type of question.

Here is a snippet of my scaled data, numeric and one hot encoding.

````
        0.        ],
       [0.21494554, 0.        , 1.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.21770302, 0.        , 1.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       ...,
       [0.2135668 , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.20681097, 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.21549704, 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ]])```
````

Comment: To do LSTM you need preprocess your data into timeseries. Maybe before you jump into timeseries or LSTM you can try to evaluate by including the timing in the original model with this cyclic transormation on your workday: `df['sin_weekday'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * df['weekday'] / 7.0)`, `df['cos_weekday'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * df['weekday'] / 7.0`

Comment: I get the concept of LSTM and time series. But not adding a one hot encoding to the numeric data is what i don't know how to go about.

Comment: - LSTM: Your workday info can be used to make the timeseries data sequence: say 1) Mon, 2) Tue, .... , and in the end you don't need this field in your ts data.  
- ORIGINAL:  Instead of using one-hot, give it a try on the cyclic transformation. Good luck :p

Comment: I get that but my time series data sequence is in every hours, so we have 24 power data for a day and this varies for different days.

Comment: I see. then you can try this `timeseries_dataset_from_array` from Keras.

Comment: yeah, but my problem is working with the one-hot-encoding data